# HTML Tables always cutted off when window.printed

Tags: php, printing

I am using a loop to dispaly records and data in html table. But the thing is when it is printed a row cuts off.

I've done so many searches here and nothing gets done on right. What should I do? Ive tested several css and scripts but still dont work.

Hope somebody could help.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: You might need `@media print` in your style sheet. You might need to change printer settings in the browser. Things depend on your browser and the system's default printer. And when using `@media print` it's best to put sizes in cm or in, since printers don't understand pixels (the same way displays do).

Comment: I got it thank you :)